# Idiomatic use of computed properties in Polymer 2

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm trying to wrap my head around how computed observables / properties in Polymer 2 work and should be used. I've created a repro analogous to my real code that zooms in on the thing I'd like to see reviewed: my use of `computed` properties in a Polymer 2 component.

Some things that might be helpful while reviewing:

- I've explicitly left out CSS and styling because I want to focus on getting the code right.
- We're targeting modern browsers, specifically for IE only Edge.

The main thing I'm worried about is `hasSelectedPerson` and its underlying "private" function. For one thing, it feels weird that I have to ask for a `person` as an argument, when it's also available as a property on the class.

```
<link rel="import" href="//polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/paper-button/paper-button.html">

<dom-module id="people-template">

  <template>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[people]]" as="person">
      <paper-button raised on-click="_onSelectClick" item="[[person]]">
        [[person.name]]
      </paper-button>
    </template>
    <template is="dom-if" if="[[hasSelectedPerson]]">
      <p>Selected: [[selectedPerson.id]] [[selectedPerson.name]]</p>
    </template>
  </template>

  <script>
    class PeopleTemplate extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() {
        return "people-template";
      }

      static get properties() {
        return {
          people: {
            type: Array,
            value: [
              { id: 1, name: "John Doe" },
              { id: 2, name: "Mary Havenstein" },
              { id: 3, name: "Janie van Staffelen" },
            ]
          },

          selectedPerson: Object,

          hasSelectedPerson: {
            type: Boolean,
            computed: "_hasSelectedPerson(selectedPerson)"
          }
        }
      }

      _onSelectClick(event) {
        this.set("selectedPerson", event.composedPath()[0].item);
      }

      _hasSelectedPerson(person) {
        return !!person;
      }
    }

    customElements.define(PeopleTemplate.is, PeopleTemplate);
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

You can also [check it on plnkr.co](https://plnkr.co/edit/VSNEnJeSJNlqxQhwhfBE?p=preview) where it's wrapped in a plain index file to see it actually running.

So, to summarize:

1. Any specific comments on my use of `computed`?
2. Any generic comments on this component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any specific comments on my use of computed?

I understand it's an *annoying* thing to have to repeat the dependencies for `computed` function but that's how Polymer can infer when that property has to be refreshed. If you had to use only the function name then it had to *analyze* your JavaScript code and it's an definitely a complex/slow task (it can't simply execute it to keep track of what you're reading because code may have side effects and/or multiple execution paths). The easiest workaround is to have you explicitly name the dependencies. Notably View.js does it for you.

Think positive: at least you do not have to add observers to all the dependencies and to manually invalidate the computed property...

> Any generic comments on this component?

Few things you can improve. First of all a non primitive default value shouldn't be an immediate value but a function. That value instance is shared across all instances of your component. Imagine you have two instances of `<people-template>` and in one of them you `push()` a new item in `people`. That new item is added to all the default instances! You should simply rewrite is as:

```
people: {
    type: Array,
    value: function () {
        return [
            { id: 1, name: "John Doe" },
            { id: 2, name: "Mary Havenstein" },
            { id: 3, name: "Janie van Staffelen" }
        ];
    }
}
```

There are, of course, cases when this *shared value* behavior is what you need (for example to implement a custom `iron-meta`-like component).

---

You set a new value for the property using `this.set()`, it's perfectly allowed but in this simple case you may also just use:

```
this.selectedPerson = event.composedPath()[0].item;
```

Of course you may decide to mark `selectedPerson` as read-only, in this case keep `this.set()` in-place.

---

I find that getting the model using `composedPath()[0]` is little bit fragile. `dom-repeat` template lets you use an easier syntax (see also [Data binding helper elements](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/templates)):

```
this.selectedPerson = event.model.item;
```

Note that `item` is the name of the item used in the `dom-repeat` template, in your case you specified another name with `as="person"` then you need to use it:

```
this.selectedPerson = event.model.person;
```

---

I find `person != null` much more clear than `return !!person` if `person` is not supposed to be a boolean value.

---

In general I'd suggest to use a prefix for your custom components and to drop `-template`. Reasoning: they're all *templates* then you repeat the obvious and using a prefix you highly reduce possible collisions with 3rd party components.

---

You have a computed property `hasSelectedPerson` you use to hide a paragraph. Few things might be optimized here:

- `dom-if` template does not need a boolean property, any *falsy* value will do the job then simply `if="[[selectedPerson]]"` is sufficient.
- `dom-if` to hide a single element without any complex logic (for example lists) is an overkill and a (small) performance hit. You can use the `hidden` attribute (eventually complimented by a specific `*[hidden]` CSS rule when there isn't browser support) to achieve the same result: `<p hidden$="[[selectedPerson]]">...</p>`.

Comment: Thanks for your insightful remarks. One question about the `event.model.item` remark: I actually implemented it like that at first (and variations of it) but could not get it to work at all. E.g. if you make only that change to my plnkr [you can see](https://plnkr.co/edit/08d6xU4FuExLsmZa7x2N?p=preview) that clicking items won't function anymore...

Comment: It's just because you named item `person` with `as="person"`. Name of the property (`item`) reflects that name. Change the code to `e.model.person` (updated my answer as well)